# Angular JS tests with Jasmine and PhantomJS, 0 Error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, angular-mock

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
            '../scripts/bower_components/angularjs/angular.js',
            '../scripts/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '../scripts/app.js',
            '../scripts/11.js',
         
            '../scripts/controllers/*.js',
            '../scripts/directives/*.js',
            '../scripts/services/*.js',
            'controllers/controllersTests.js',
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'PhantomJS_custom'],

    customLaunchers: {
      'PhantomJS_custom': {
        base: 'PhantomJS',
        options: {
          windowName: 'my-window',
          settings: {
            webSecurityEnabled: false
          },
        },
        flags: ['--load-images=true'],
        debug: false
      }
    },

    phantomjsLauncher: {
      // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered (useful if karma exits without killing phantom)
      exitOnResourceError: true
    },
    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

I need to test code of controllers, but i can't see right result, code below:
"slide" array length = 4; but in test i write "toBe(2)" and i see:

PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.035 secs / 0 secs)

Why i see 0 errors, if I expect 2, but array length is 4 ???

```js
app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.slide = [1, 2, 3, 4];
}]);
```

```js
describe('Tests Controllers', function() {
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope){
    $controller = _$controller_;

    it('check slides length, it should be 4', function() {
      var $scope = {};
      var controller = $controller('mainCtrl', { $scope: $scope });
      expect($scope.slide.length).toBe(2);
    });
  }));
});
```

Comment: Your test file does not even get executed, seems to be an issue in the setup. Is it your first test for your application? Is Karma configured properly?

Comment: Yes, it is my first test. I've attached karma config.

Comment: Could you share your Karma configuration file?

Comment: sure, done, you can see it!

Comment: Oh, I see what might be the issue. You are not supposed to put `it` block inside `beforeEach`, they have to be on the same level. You'll have to put your `it` **after** the second `beforeEach` according to your code sample, not inside.

Comment: Yes, thank you. But now, i have an error " TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$controller('mainCtrl', { $scope: $scope })')
"

Comment: Can you update your code in the question so I could see how it looks like now?

Answer (score 3):

When Karma can't find your tests and displays `Executed 0 of 0 ERROR`, the most popular reasons which lead to this behavior are:

- bad path to a test file/folder in `karma.conf.js` in the `files:[]` option
- missing specs (`it` blocks) in the test file/folder, so Karma has nothing to execute. It may occur also if specs are placed inappropriately within a test file, like in your case you've put `it` inside `beforeEach`, but Jasmine does not support it. The idea is to put them on the same level. `it` spec can live separately in the global scope or right within `describe` suite blocks.

Comment: If it's intentional that there are 0 tests, is there a way to tell Karma not to treat this 0 of 0 as an error?

Comment: @core, I guess it's by design, take a look at [source code here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/browser.js#L137) - if there is no tests, then a [number of success tests](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/browser_result.js#L16) is 0, which is falsy, so it's considered an error. Maybe creating one dummy spec will work for you?

Comment: @core you can add `failOnEmptyTestSuite: false` to your karma.conf.js